# Edit query in preparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, edit

Is it possible to edit a preparedStatement that was used before in another Method?
For example:

```
public class MyDB {
private Connection c;
private PreparedStatement p;

public void foo() {
    // connecting to DB...try-catch-block...
    p = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM t WHERE NAME=?");
    p.setString(1, "Tom");

}

public void boo(){
    // connecting to DB...try-catch-block...        
    //Here I want to concat the query with something
    --> p = ....." AND City=?";
    p.setString(2, "London");

    ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();
    [...]


}
}
```

Comment: can you explain more what you try to accomplish plz?

Comment: No, not really.  You could create a series of `static final` `String`s which form the basic query and append to them.  Also, the point of a `PreparedStatement` is so you don't put the query logic within in it (ie `" AND City='London'"` is wrong, it should be `" AND City=?"`)

Comment: ooops sorry, Ive fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: *no*. Long answer: not really, and you don't seem to be using the `PreparedStatement` correctly. You could do something like -

```
private String query = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE NAME=?";
public void foo() {
    // connecting to DB...try-catch-block...
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try (PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(query);) {
        ps.setString(1, "Tom");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void boo() {
    // connecting to DB...try-catch-block...
    // Here I want to concat the query with something
    String sql = query + " AND City=?";
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try (PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);) {
        ps.setString(1, "Tom");
        ps.setString(2, "London");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```